# Escaping closure captures mutating self in Swift Combine Subscriber

Tags: swift, combine

So i have this strict with a function that calls a Combine publisher, with the purpose of passing in the results to another function. I am getting the following error:
[image: Error message]

My code snippet is:

```swift
public func execute(state: FluxState?, dispatch: @escaping DispatchFunction) {
            let config = Popular(country: .usa, genres: nil)

            subscriptions = []

            let params = [
                "page": "\(self.page)",
                "per_page": "\(20)"
            ]
            print("on page \(self.page)")

            var moviesResult = [Movie]()

            SwiftRecommendations.APIService.shared
                .getMovies(settings: config, params: params)
                //.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
                    if case let .failure(error) = completion {
                        print("error \(error)")
                    } else {
                        self.popularMovies = moviesResult
                        dispatch(SetMovieMenuList(page: self.page,
                            list: MovieSwift.MoviesMenu.popular,
                            response: moviesResult))
                    }
                }, receiveValue: { [unowned self] in
                    moviesResult = $0
                })
                .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
        }
    }
```

The `SetMovieMenuList` snippet is:

```swift
class SetMovieMenuList: Action {
        let page: Int
        let list: MoviesMenu
        let response: [Movie]
    }
```

The dispatch function is a SwiftFlux state, and APIService is a struct. Not sure if I need to provide any additional information, but I wanted to see if this was the way to structure this, or how do I use `subscriptions` and persist the list of movies in this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Escaping+closure+captures+mutating+self. You cannot use a struct this way.

Comment: Sorry can you provide a bit more information

Comment: The linked answers should provide the details. When you pass a struct to a closure, it makes a copy, so the `self` inside the closure is not the same `self` outside the closure. Any mutation you make inside the closure will not be seen outside. If you need to have multiple references to the same object, then you need a reference type (a class).

Comment: Right, so when i change `SetMovieMenuList` to a class, set `FetchMoviesMenuList` and `MoviesAction` to class as well, the error goes away but it crashes in the same code block because of already unallocated reference.

Comment: This likely means you're trying to modify an object on an arbitrary thread. Objects are not thread-safe unless you do things to make them so. You need to make sure that all actions occur on one dispatch queue. You likely want to add a `receive(on:)` in your chain to make sure that the handling is done on the queue you expect.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier. So ill try working with `receive(on:)` thread wise but as far as struct versus class, which approach should I be taking, and what should/can be a struct, what should/can be a class in this workflow

Comment: I don't know what all the parts here are trying to do, but the key thing is this: if the only thing you care about is the values of the properties, then it's probably a value (a struct). If you also care about the identity (so two things with the exact same property values could be different "things") then you want a reference type (a class). So, for example, if you want to observe something, that something would have to be a reference (you can't observe "4" itself, a value; you can only observe a thing that contains 4, a reference).

Comment: Typically something like an APIService would be class, since you only want one of them (and every time you pass a struct, you're making an independent copy). The fact that you can configure it strongly indicates that it's really a reference type, since it has internal state that you want to share. (But your API is a bit confusing, because what if two things are running at the same time and each sets the API token to different things?)

Comment: The fact that you want some async operation to modify `MoviesActions.subscriptions` similarly strongly suggests that this should be a class (but this is very confusing because it looks like `.subscriptions` is a static property, which also seems very wrong).

Comment: Right thanks... I had `subscriptions` as static because its in a struct and got that self error. But it does sound like I should referencing and only having one reference rather than values...Thanks !

Comment: @RobNapier so i have them all as classes, tested with .receive(on: in both maintop as well as background, and still get the crash. I can't even do static analyzer or anything to pause to prove who the culprit is. This is quite frustrating.. argh

Comment: I would put this together as a new question, including details of the crash, and ideally a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. (Just creating that example, finding out which pieces are required to create the crash, will often lead you to the solution.) If it's an actual memory error (rather than an assertion crash), then it is almost always due to cross-thread access, or using `Unsafe` types. Otherwise, Swift is safe and should not be able to incorrectly access memory. More often "crash" is an assertion, however, and you should read the messages printed carefully.

Comment: Sounds fair thanks. Yeah I’ll do that